# Php gzcompress android decompress

Tags: php, android, compression

I was trying to compress a String in php using the following code.

```
<?php
$compressed   = gzcompress('Compress me', 9);    
echo $uncompressed;
?>

The compressed string is "xÚsÎÏ-(J-.VÈM½?".
```

But when tried to decompress this in java using the following function

```
public static String unzipString(String zippedText) {
    String unzipped = null;
    try {
        byte[] zbytes = zippedText.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        // Add extra byte to array when Inflater is set to true
        byte[] input = new byte[zbytes.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(zbytes, 0, input, 0, zbytes.length);
        input[zbytes.length] = 0;
        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
        InflaterInputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(bin);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
            bout.write(b);
        }
        bout.close();
        unzipped = bout.toString();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        printIoError(io);
    }
    return unzipped;
}
```

I was getting null string..Please correct me if i did something wrong this code.